# How to define alias on case condition mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am trying to move my one column to another one by changing the values but since the column names are not match (one is role_id and other one is challenge_id) I try to do create an alias **as role_id** it is not working.
is my current query.

I try to do

```
INSERT into role_user (role_id, user_id) 
            SELECT CASE 
                WHEN challenge_id=2 Then 6
                When challenge_id=3 then 7
                when challenge_id=4 then 8 
                when challenge_id=1 then 9
                END
                challenge_id as role_id , user_id
                FROM challenge_user
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a redundant "challenge id" between the the "END" and the "AS":

```
INSERT into role_user (role_id, user_id) 
            SELECT CASE 
                WHEN challenge_id=2 Then 6
                When challenge_id=3 then 7
                when challenge_id=4 then 8 
                when challenge_id=1 then 9
                END
                AS role_id,  -- Here!
                user_id
                FROM challenge_user
```

Moreover, since you aren't really using this alias for anything (just inserting it directly to another table), you could just drop it completely:

```
INSERT into role_user (role_id, user_id) 
            SELECT CASE 
                WHEN challenge_id=2 Then 6
                When challenge_id=3 then 7
                when challenge_id=4 then 8 
                when challenge_id=1 then 9
                END,
                user_id
                FROM challenge_user
```